# How to import SBT dependencies manually in intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I want to use Intellij as Spark and Scala editor so I should create an SBT project. Scala and SBT plugins are installed, but the problem is when I create SBT project, at the first it try to fetch SBT plugins and dependencies from [here](http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/) but it stuck on `sbt getting org.scala-sbt 0.13.13` step! sometime it progresses but finally errors time out! I have access to address SBT want get dependencies by browser and I want to know is it possible to download dependencies manually and put in the right place ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the detailed steps in [this chapter](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch18s12.html) of Scala Cookbook. In build.sbt file you should add a resolver key including the Ivy repository you want.

```
resolvers += "Your Repository" at "Repository Location"
```